# How to manage User Accounts in MediaWiki via Database?

Tags: mediawiki

I installed the MediaWiki, but forgot both username and password, can some one help to to retrieve User Name and Password.

Comment: This question doesn't look related to programming directly, please consider using another site for this question, for example - https://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: FAQ: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#Initial_user_was_not_created_by_installer_or_it_is_not_an_administrator

Answer (score 3):

Do you have shell access? You can run the [CreateAndPromote](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CreateAndPromote.php) maintenance script:

```
$ php maintenance/createAndPromote.php --bureaucrat --sysop --force YourUsername Y0urN3wPassw0rd
```